# How to follow MVC architecture in web app Using Node, Express, Postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, model-view-controller

I'm unsure of how to apply the MVC architecture to my node web app, in specific separating the model from the controller.

The current structure has the views separated properly (all my .ejs files) and then I guess that my `app.js` is like the controller as it contains all the routes to respond to http requests. The routes are then handled in a `queries.js` file which is where I query my database using `node-postgres` (most of the views rendered are either displaying information from the database or displaying forms so the user can insert data to the database). Should I be doing this differently, or more specifically should I try to create a model that contains raw data from the database and have the route handlers manipulate this data instead of directly querying the database (not sure how I would handle inserting into the database then...)? I'm just concerned that the current way I have structured my web app will make it difficult to manage as it grows and difficult for other to understand and add on to.

Here is an example of how the web app is currently structured: Say a user clicks a button to display all the active orders, my `app.js` file would look something like this

```
const db = require('./queries')

app.get('/activeorders', db.getActiveOrders)
```

My `queries.js` file would then handle this route like so:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.USER,
  host: process.env.HOST,
  database: process.env.DB,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.PORT,
})

const getActiveOrders = (request, response) => {
    const queryOrders = 'SELECT * FROM orders WHERE complete=0 ORDER BY date_rec DESC;';
    pool.query(queryOrders, (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            throw error
        }
        var ordersObj = results.rows;
        response.render('pages/activeorders', {
            ordersObj: ordersObj
        })
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getActiveOrders,
}
```

As can be seen in the handler the database is queried and stores the results in an object that is then passed to the `activeorders.ejs` file when rendered.

Comment: The above code is directly mapping the result set of a db query to UI. This makes the UI tightly coupled with your entity (orders in this case), which does not follow the MVC pattern. Any changes done to your orders table has a direct impact in the UI page implementation 'activeorders'.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran How would I avoid this? Would I create a "model" that gets all the information needed from the database and the have the route handlers access that data?

Comment: In your case, for the order business entity you would create a model class, and  you would use some ORM framework to map the retrieved order records from db to these model class.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Would using a query builder such as Knex be able to accomplish something similar?

Comment: Knex is helping to abstract the query building to target particular database engine, you need more than that. You should look at something like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/), an object relation mapping (ORM) framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using a middleware allowing you to make an API from a Postgresql database.

Any change made on the databases will be propagated and available to you API. It will also let a lot of modularity to possible filters/ select ...

And for complex queries DBA will be able to develop stored procs available to everyone by API. That is the **Model** layer. Only SQL exposed through a middleware.

**Controller** will be how you made you API calls and data transformations if needed to refresh data based in you **View**

Abstracting the model layer with a middleware definitely a huge economy on time.

For postgres majors options : [postgres](https://postgrest.org/en/v8.0/) & [pgrest](https://prestd.com/)

Comment: thanks to to the tipos fixes ( not an english speaker ;) )

Comment: No problem haha, thanks for the answer I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In MVC pattern we split each part of the application because this approach to software development for complex needs by connecting the implementation to an evolving model

I suggest you visit [sample-mvc-express-postgres](https://github.com/GainorB/node-express-mvc) to understand structure code

If you are interested in design pattern, visit https://dev.to/salah856/implementing-domain-driven-design-part-i-5a72, This link explains how to use DDD in your application and show how to design each layer of the application

Answer (score 0):

Set `app.js` as root file and create a controller and a model folder. Define all models in `model` folder, while in controller first import model files handlers and create all APIs or queries function. Then in the root app.js file import controller functions handler and run it.

[image: this image contain folder structure]